# Automatically execute a method before another methods in Delphi with RAD XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Good day,

I code some classes `TFoo` and `TBar`. They have a few of methods that need calling a swithcing function `TFoo.switch` and `TBar.switch`.

```
TBaseFooBar = class
  strict private
    FNumConfig: Word;
  protected
    procedure Switch;  
end;
```

This super class has a private field `FNumConfig` which describe the number of PCI-card. The `Switch` method uses function from some library:

```
procedure TBaseFooBar.Switch;  
begin
  tmkselect(FNumConfig);
end;
```

I would like to ask you is there a way to call a super function `Switch` before executing any `DoSomethingWithFoo()` or `DoSomethingWithBar()` respectivly? 
I mean something like this

```
TFoo = class(TBaseFooBar )
  { FNumConfig: Word; // this number declares the number of a PCI card}
  public 

  @Switch // before this method
  procedure DoSomethingWithFoo1();

// ...
  @Switch // and before this one
  procedure DoSomethingWithFooN();

// before this one there is no calling of Switch
  function NotSwitching();
end;
```

And the `TBar` class

```
TBar = class(TBaseFooBar )
{  FNumConfig: Word; // this is another one number declares of another PCI card, they are not equal. }
public 
@Switch // before this method
  procedure DoSomethingWithBar1();
// ...
@Switch // and before this one
  procedure DoSomethingWithBarN();
end;
```

I know about a simple method:

```
procedure TFoo.DoSomethingWithFoo1();  
begin
Switch();
// and another stuff.
end;
```

but I would like to write all it in one place - in a declaration of classes.

Comment: In case I understood you correctly (`TBaseFooBar` is pretty much `sealed` and you cannot extend it with optional hook methods), the `TVirtualMethodInterceptor` is probably what you're looking for. Rob Kennedy's answer links to a discussion about those.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi doesn't support anything like that built in. What you're asking for is essentially an aspect-oriented-programming feature. There are some options for that from third-party vendors, which [have been discussed here before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197731/33732).

Answer (score 0):

There are some object-oriented design patterns which could be useful to solve this:

- Command pattern
- Decorator pattern
- Strategy pattern

This means: operations could be implemented as "Command" objects, which are decorated by a "Switcher" class where needed.