# Meta-Programming in Delphi - Adding a function call to every method of a class

Tags: delphi, metaprogramming, aop

I'm wanting to add some instrumentation to an application, basically I want to add a function call as the first line to every method/event in a number of datamodules, the code roughly looks like.

```
procedure TSomeClass.SomeProcedure;   
begin
  ExecutionCounter(ClassName, 'SomeProcedure'); //This is what I want to insert.
  //the rest of the procedure
end;
```

I could do this manually to the thousands of methods (would likely take a few hours), but I was wondering if there was some programmatic way of doing this.

I could remove the code fairly easily with a regular expression, but can't think of a way to add it (determine the first `begin` after `procedure` or `function` and insert the code with the appropriate parameters).

This would be a great case for AOP in Delphi, but it is not very well supported.

For some background, I'm working with a large legacy application server (DataSnap/DCOM) and I'm wanting to determine what functions are still being called by the client.  The ExecutionCounter function returns a class as an interface, in the classes destructor it logs the class name, method name, increments the execution count and total running time for that method (in a separate thread of course).

Comment: I think a commercial application like aw time or maybe even eureka log would be a better solution.  Otherwise try doing via rtti and run in debug mode

Comment: You could probably use [GPProfile](http://code.google.com/p/gpprofile2011/wiki/GpProfile) as a starting point, modifying its payload as necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically execute a method before another methods in Delphi with RAD XE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832277/automatically-execute-a-method-before-another-methods-in-delphi-with-rad-xe)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not really a duplicate of this question, I'm happy to change the code, just wanting to avoid doing it manually.

Comment: @TobyAllen I was hoping to avoid a third party profiler as this will be running on a remote server in production (eventually).  My intention was to log the data to a database over a long period of time to build up some statistics.

Comment: You mean you want to run a script to modify the code for you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yup, I'd be happy with that - or some other solution

Comment: The CodeSite Method Tracer has a similar functionality. I don't know if this will help in your specific case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did this somewhat manually.  There were 647 methods that I added the function call.  My solution was to use the scripting in CnPack, I wrote the following script

```
program InsertInstrumentation;

{
  Note: Please Add this Script to Script Library, and Run it from the
    Corresponding item of the Dropdown Menu under "Run" ToolButton in
    Script Window. Or Assign a Shortcut to Run it.
}

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs;
var
  EditView: IOTAEditView;
  Proc : string;
  dotpos : integer;
begin
  EditView := CnOtaGetTopMostEditView(nil);
  if EditView <> nil then
    EditView.GetPosition.MoveBOL; // Move the cursor to the beginning of the line
  proc := CnOtaGetCurrentProcedure;
  dotPos := pos('.', proc);
  if dotPos > 0 then //remove the class name if it is present
    Delete(Proc, 1, dotPos);
  IdeInsertTextIntoEditor('  ExecutionCounter(ClassName, ''' + Proc + ''');' + #13#10);
end.
```

It added `ExecutionCounter(ClassName, 'TheCurrentMethodName');` as a new line at the current cursor position.  I assigned it to CTRL+SHIFT+Q and worked my way through the application.  Was a bit manual but took a bit over an hour to do.  Would have liked to have come up with some mechanism to do it automatically - I guess I should probably learn Ruby or Perl or some other scripting language.

Comment: Yes, you should learn a scripting language. At least one. Resorting to scripting the IDE to modify text files is not very efficient.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have done some Ruby, PHP, Perl and of course JavaScript, but not enough to be able to write a rough pascal parser in the time I had available.  I will need to find some time to learn one properly as it is handy doing bulk changes to code and sometimes regular expressions aren't quite enough.

Comment: You do need such a tool in your bag. Myself I use Python a lot but it matters more that you know one scripting language that which one. That said, the three you listed are not ideal for the needs discussed here. By the way, you should surely accept answers to old questions. You've got plenty that could be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

DSharp (https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp) has a form of aspects. All methods need to be virtual so that is a very real limitation but this might be something that you can use.

Here is a link to his AOP example:

https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp/src/ad7c5983505f0117f1347f92d2bb96c07bdfda94/Samples/AOP/?at=master

For your example you would do something like this:

```
TMyAspect = class(TAspect)
public
  class procedure DoBefore(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
    const Args: TArray<TValue>; out DoInvoke: Boolean; out Result: TValue); override;
end;
```

The implementation would probably look something like this:

```
class procedure TMyAspect.DoBefore(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
  const Args: TArray<TValue>; out DoInvoke: Boolean; out Result: TValue);
begin
  inherited;
  ExecutionCounter(Instance.ClassName, Method.Name);
end;
```

And you would hook it onto the method like this:

```
AspectWeaver.AddAspect(TSomeClass, TMyAspect, 'SomeProcedure');
```